# Fazer .append() antes de .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou a utilizar o `.load()` para carregar conteúdo (partial) a partir do `controller` da minha aplicação. O que queria fazer antes do `.load`, era adicionar código `html` ao mesmo tempo que carrego uma partial.

Para tal tentei fazer `.append` antes do `.load`:

`$("#Produto").append($('<br />')).load('/ContratoCli/carregaProduto', { serie: $("#Serie").val(), numDoc: $("#NumDoc").val() })`;

O que está a acontecer é que o `load` utiliza a `div` toda e não consigo adicionar o `<br />` antes (apaga e faz o load por cima), ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que consigo contornar isto?

Comment: E se usar um prepend (http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) depois do load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o `.load()` vai sempre substituir o conteúdo do elemento.
O que você pode fazer é utilizar o método `.get()` e dentro dele o `.append()`, veja:

```
$.get('/ContratoCli/carregaProduto', {serie: $("#Serie").val(), numDoc: $("#NumDoc").val()}, function(data) {   
    $('#Produto').append($('<br />')).append(data);
});
```

Comment: Era exactamente esse o problema, e é esta a solução! Thanks